# Modify this rewrite to ignore .php extension in query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This rewrite rule works just fine to remove .php extension, but in the case where a file name is passed in the query string, it tries to remove the extension there too. How to make it ignore the query string?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
```

Comment: No, it does not. Please do your homework, and check on an actual system before asking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Gerben, but perhaps you can add substance to it? The rule has been tested and does work. Perhaps you misunderstood the question?

Comment: Sorry. The RewriteCond will indeed match a querystring, but this is where the RewriteRule comes in. The RewriteRule only matches the path-part of the url, and never contains the querystring. So the `(.*)\.php$` will never match if `.php` is only in the querystring. So the two combined should never, ever, match a url with only `.php` in the querystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `(.*)` match in the rewrite condition more strict. Right now, it's matching the URI *or* the query string. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ ([^\?]+)\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
```

The `[^\?]+` will match anything that isn't a `?`. Removing the `\ HTTP` ensures that a query string could follow the `.php`.